# How to find the LimInf of a sequence of RV's

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I have an indipendent sequence of Rv's $Y_n$ with law that eventually is:

$\mathbb{P}(Y_n<a) = \begin{cases} 0 & \mbox{if}\ a \leq 0 \\ 1 - \frac{1}{n^{2\gamma}a^2}& \mbox{if}\ a >0\end{cases}$

I would like to find $\lim \inf Y_n$.

I know that it has to be a constant due to the independence of the random variables.

I tried to "converting" the lim inf in a lim sup using the usual de morgan forumulas and then applying Borel Cantelli, but something goes wrong and I'm unable to proceed.

Intuitively is "obviously" $0$, indeed.

A little help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
For every $\epsilon > 0$

$\sum_{n \geq1}\mathbb{P}(Y_n < -\epsilon) < \infty$

then $\mathbb{P}(\lim \sup\{ Y_n< -\epsilon \})= 0$ for Borel Cantelli 1. This is equivalent to $\mathbb{P}(\lim \inf\{ Y_n \geq -\epsilon \})= 1$.

In addition $\sum_{n \geq1}\mathbb{P}(Y_n \leq \epsilon) = \infty$

then  $\mathbb{P}(\lim \sup\{ Y_n \leq \epsilon \})= 1$ for Borel Cantelli 2. This is equivalent to $\mathbb{P}(\lim \inf\{ Y_n > \epsilon \})= 0$

The result that $\lim \inf Y_n = 0$ follows.